How do I format date on ssrs report?
In an SSRS report I need to show today's date and current time.
I tried this =Day =Mouth and =Year but this is not working, it is giving an error.
How can I write this expression ?
I want output display like this: 20th day of June 2024

For a text box value, there can only be one expression. You can use a date function but need to speciify the date field. The different parts can be combined with an & sign for text.
=Day(Fields!DATE_FIELD.Value) & "th day of " & MonthName(Month(Fields!DATE_FIELD.Value), 0) & " " & Year(Fields!DATE_FIELD.Value)

The Month function returns the month number so the MonthName function is needed to convert the number to a name.
Unfortunately, there's not an automatic function for the "th" for 1st, 2nd, 3rd so you may need to add a SWITCH function for Fields!DATE_FIELD.Value MOD 10 to identify those and use the right suffix.

I am getting an error on =Day(Fields!DATE_FIELD.Value)??

You need to use your date field where DATE_FIELD is. See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/tutorial-introducing-expressions?view=sql-server-ver16

I realize I don't have date on my dataset which I don't need I think  but let me clarify my question the only thing I is just the today date in month like: Today is 14th day of August  2024

Then you would use the TODAY() function instead of the date field - =Day(TODAY()) & "th day of " & MonthName(Month(TODAY()), 0) & " " & Year(TODAY())
